# Mutual row shuffling of ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n by d matrix X, d by 1 vector w, and n by 1 vector y such that Xw = y

I would like to shuffle the rows of X and y mutually. Meaning the shuffling itself can be random, as long as it is applied to both X and y. If for instance row 20 in X became row 3 in X, then row 20 in y will become row 3 in y.

I wrote this code:

```
def train_test_split(X, y, w, training_percentage=80):
    print(np.linalg.norm(X @ w - y))
    permutation = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
    np.take(X, permutation, axis=0, out=X)
    np.take(y, permutation, axis=0, out=y)
    print(np.linalg.norm(X @ w - y))
```

the first print is zero. The second print is 1.4345819474787535e-09 which is not zero (although it's close).

Is this a round off issue or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Looks correct.  Depending on the value sizes of X and w, it is most likely a precision error.

Comment: They are random real numbers between -100 and 100. Why would shuffling the rows have an effect in precision though? it's the exact same calculation

Comment: It is mathematically the same calculation, but not numerically.  Matrix multiplication is an expensive operation and so it is optimized.  It probably uses accumulators for the sums rather than explicit sums, which can show precision errors.

Comment: I am getting the same results from the 2 prints and do not see anything wrong with the code. Hint: if you return the two vectors X@w-y and the permutation, you can check one permutes into the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(a+b)+(c+d)` might not equal to `(a+c) + (b+d)` due to floating point precision.

A simple experiment for this:

```
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.rand(100)

# randomly shuffle and take the sum
sum_arr = [np.random.permutation(a).sum() for _ in range(100)]

# check if sum_arr contains unique value:
np.min(sum_arr) == np.max(sum_arr)
# Output: False
```